# Replace all values that differ from the value "NA"

Tags: r, replace, na

I seem to have stumbled upon a predicament in my efforts to learn using R. I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
col1  /   col2  /   col3   

NA  / 1 /  2

1  /  NA  /2
```

What I need to do is replace everything that IS NOT NA with another value (see below)

```
Col1  /  col2  /    col 3

NA / Data / Data

Data / NA/ Data
```

I've looked everywhere on the web, it seems that everybody wants to replace `NA`'s with other values, I on the other hand need the exact opposite but was unable to find any command. I even looked into "IF's" but was only able to find functions that replace values if they are eiter `<` or `=` or `>` to a certain number. I need something that will specify..."IF different from `NA`, then replace with...."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data:

```
dat <- data.frame(col1 = c(NA, 1), col2 = c(1, NA), col3 = c(2, 2))
```

To choose all values that are *not* `NA`, use the logical operator `!` ("not") together with `is.na`:

```
dat[!is.na(dat)] <- "Data"

  col1 col2 col3
1 <NA> Data Data
2 Data <NA> Data
```

The same can also be achieved with the `replace` function:

```
replace(dat, !is.na(dat), "Data")
```

---

Another approach is needed if you want to replace the values of factors. This can be achieved with the following command:

```
replace(data.frame(lapply(dat, as.character), stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
        !is.na(dat), "Data")
```

Comment: The only issue with this approach is that it makes a complete copy of an object the same size as dat

Comment: @mnel not entirely, `!is.na(dat)` results in a logical matrix, which is a smaller object than the original data frame. `object.size(dat)` results in 568 bytes and  `object.size(!is.na(dat))` in 368 bytes. Also it can probably not be helped. If the object is that large that this will cause memory problems then doing it cell by cell (e.g., with two loops) will probably be intolerably slow.

Comment: Unfortunately none of the suggestions work for me.

dat <- data.frame(col1 = c(NA, 1), col2 = c(1, NA), col3 = c(2, 2))

The above I cannot use, because what I named in my example as 1, 2, in my real dataframe I can have even 1 million unique values.

dat[!is.na(dat)] <- "Data"

This gives me this error and it seems to generate NA's for all values in the dataframe 8: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = "Data") :
  invalid factor level, NAs generated
replace(dat, !is.na(dat), "Data")
This one gives me the exact same error as the above.I guess I'll have to keep on looking

David

Comment: Also I forgot to mention that my data is not formed of factors, it is formed of unique categorical values. Thank you so much anyway. All the best. David

Comment: David, I think you're missing the point.  Given your matrix `dat`, and some *other* array of values to paste into `dat`, the expression `dat[!is.na(dat)] <- Data` will do fine.  If you are having problems with your `Data` array, please post a useful sample and tell us what sort of elements (numeric, factor,etc) populate that array.

Comment: Ok. Well I don't know how to share an image for you to see my dataframe so I'll describe it instead. In the first column I have the country abreviation (GB, US, CA, IT). In the second column I have the postcode or zipcode (N1, SW10). In the third column I have the source where the user came from , in the format of an ULR (http://googleclick...) but also in this third column, not all the cells have an URL. Some of the cells have NA, meaning that the user came to my webpage virally. I want to replace in column no 3 ONLY, everything that is not NA with something else. Does this make sense?

Comment: replace(data.frame(lapply(dat, as.character), stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
        !is.na(dat), "Data")   This one seems to work fine, except that it replaces EVERYTHING, all the columns with NA. IS it possible to use this function but put a condition to modify only a specific column?

Comment: @DavidRogers To replace all non-`NA` values in the third column of a data frame, use this command: `dat[3] <- as.character(dat[[3]]); dat[!is.na(dat[3]), 3] <- "Data"`

Comment: Thank you Sven but this does not seem to work for me. In your function when you say "3" does that mean column name or column index? It gives me an error when I replace "3" with the column name saying that it does not find the column , although it exists. This is the formula I used file4 <- file1[Source] <- as.character(file1[[Source]]); file1[!is.na(file1[Source]), Source] <- "Data". And this is the error it gave me Error in (function(x, i, exact) if (is.matrix(i)) as.matrix(x)[[i]] else .subset2(x,  : 
  object 'Source' not found. The column exists though.

Comment: @DavidRogers In my example, `3` was the index of the third column. If you want to use the name of the column (`Source`), you have to put it between quotation marks (`"Source"`).

Comment: Thank you so much Sven, that solved it. I am novice at R. Many thanks again. All the best    David